# mergeMap does not exist on type observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs, reactivex, rxjs6

I am trying to use `mergeMap` in `rxjs6` and i am getting this error:

`Property 'mergeMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>'`

I have tried `import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';` and it is not working.

What am i doing wrong?

---

```
import {from, Observable} from 'rxjs';

export class Test {

    public doSomething(): Observable<any> {
        return from(...).mergeMap();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's correct, the "patch" style of operators has been removed since RxJS 6. You should better update your code to use only "pipeable" operators or install `rxjs-compat` package that provides backwards compatibility with RxJS 5.

For more detailed description see official doc: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

... more specifically this part: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#backwards-compatibility

Comment: Thanks @martin. I used the provided information to fix my issue with the `pipe` operator. Posted my solution as well.

Comment: The doc links aren't working any more. Let's try to update your references @martin

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to the answer given by @martin, i was able to get it working with the new `pipe` operations in `rxjs6`. Here is my working code.

```
import {from, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

export class Test {

    public doSomething(): Observable<any> {
        return from(...).pipe(mergeMap(...));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Import the individual operators, then use pipe instead of chaining.

```
import { map, filter, catchError, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

source.pipe(
  map(x => x + x),
  mergeMap(n => of(n + 1, n + 2).pipe(
    filter(x => x % 1 == 0),
    scan((acc, x) => acc + x, 0),
  )),
  catchError(err => of('error found')),
).subscribe(printResult);
```

Source: https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-rxjs-6/

Answer (score 0):

**Component Html Goes like this**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="input first" id="input1">
<input type="text" id="input2" placeholder="input second">
<span></span>
```

**import required functions**

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs'
import { map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators'


var span = document.querySelector('span');
var input1 = document.querySelector('#input1');
var input2 = document.querySelector('#input2');

var obs1 = fromEvent(input1, 'input');
var obs2 = fromEvent(input2, 'input');

var obs1 = fromEvent(input1, 'input');
var obs2 = fromEvent(input2, 'input');

obs1.pipe(mergeMap(event1 => obs2.pipe(
      map(event2 => (<HTMLInputElement>event1.target).value
        + " "
        + (<HTMLInputElement>event2.target).value))))
      .subscribe((result) => {
       span.textContent=result;
      })
```